# How does this kind of gyroscope work?

Tags: gyroscope

I have seen a documentary about making [BGM-71 TOW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BGM-71_TOW) (an anti-tank missile - the Iranians make it). You can see it in this [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRkkwmHH7QU) (part 1). Between 6:08 to 6:40 minute of clip, you can see a gyroscope. I would like to know how this gyroscope works. How did they connect it to their electronic circuits?

Comment: You might like these videos by Mike from the UK https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DdbZAVyjuMg and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AO7pn3uiWA0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simply a gyroscope - meaning a flat spinning disk that has three axis decoupled through bearings for yaw,pitch and roll.  You need to read the common platform angular displacement from the mount to determine the amount of rotational movement.  So a shaft encoder on each of the axis'.  However, it's not as simple as that, as you need to consider precession and wind-down (loss of rotational speed due to friction).